# npm run server: Missing script

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to install [ng-toolkit/universal](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit) and there are terminal 3 commands to set it up. I'm having trouble running the third command (`npm run server`). The error it gives me says:

```
Missing script: "server". To see a list of scripts, run: npm run
```

So I open my package.json and look under the 'scripts'. There is no 'server' entry. How do I know what this library is supposed to run under this command?

Answer (score 0):

Under ng-toolkit/application/package.json `"server": "node local.js"` [link](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/blob/master/application/package.json)

Comment: I included the file local.js into my root directory and now it's being read. But I'm getting an error from local.js: `Cannot find module './dist/server'`. I added server.ts with the files listed at the github page but it's including other dependencies and I have no idea where they came from.

Answer (score 0):

The serve script will only work in the directory where the toolkit is installed.